# React project compiled with problems, check the render method in 'App'

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

I cant compile my react project because i get this error

[right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUtqF.png)

And i dont know what to do to get rid of this

It say that check the render method of 'App' so here is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
// import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation.js';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn/SignIn.js';
import Register from './components/Register/Register.js';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar.js';
import TextBox from './components/TextBox/TextBox.js';
import ParticlesBg from 'particles-bg'
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      route: 'home',
      isSignedIn: false,
      text: ""
    }
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  handleClick = (newText) => {
      this.setState({ text: newText});
    }
  

  render() {
    const {route} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ParticlesBg type="cobweb" bg={true} color="#FFFFFF" />
        { route === 'home'
          ? <div className='row'> 
            <Sidebar  handleClick={this.handleClick} />
            <TextBox text={this.state.text}/> 
          </div>
          : (
             route === 'signin'
             ? <SignIn loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  };
};


export default App;
```

I tried search on the internet but i didnt find anything

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)